# How many possible combination of atoms are there in the universe.

Tags: factorial

I was having a discussion with a friend about approximately how many atoms there were in the universe. Google states it's around 10^78 . We then discussed how many different combinations of these atoms were possible, which is factorial 10^78.

Could someone please tell me (rounded up or down) what number is 10^78!
The only answer I can get is infinity, but how could that be if I'm using a finite number?

I know little about math and I'm hoping someone could help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use Stirling's approximation to get an idea.

Comment: I really can't tell if this is a troll. The original question is silly...what does that even mean? But, about the math question: you can get an idea of how big $10^{78}!$ is by using logarithms to approximate the number of digits in that number. Or Sterling's magic for even a better idea.

Comment: No I'm not a troll all I wanted to know is how many possible combinations of atoms are there in the universe. If we were to build a computer simulation of our universe starting from the big bang, how many possible combinations of atoms would I have to cater for?

Comment: Just for entertainment, I tried to plug the numbers into a python program (there's a handy-dandy factorial function). I get errors telling me it is too big. =) (I'm sure there's a way to do it in python, but...)

Comment: @heather : suppose there was such a function,do you think there is enough memory or storage in the world/universe to store or display that number? why should you think not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following from Lovsovs's answer:

[$\sqrt{2 \pi} \approx 10^{0.4} $](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5Ex%20%3D%20sqrt(2%20pi))

[$e \approx 10^{0.4}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5Ex%20%3D%20e)

So we have $10^{39.4} \cdot (10^{77.6})^{10^{78}}$

Following the same process as before, we get a final value of $10^{10^{80}+39.4}$, or just about

$$10^{10^{80}}$$

The stuff from the Reddit link actually comes from this nice [Vsauce video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObiqJzfyACM) on youtube (time $15:53$). He gives more examples than the Reddit page, and makes the remark that every time you shuffle a deck of cards, you almost certainly put the cards in an order in which they have never been before in the history of cards.

Comment: I watched the Vsauce video, an entertaining insight on how mind-bogglingly big factorial 52 is. Thank you for the link and your answer.

Comment: @Jaytec You're welcome, it is indeed a really cool video

Answer (score 4):

You get $\infty$ on your calculator because it is too big a number for it to handle. By using Sterling's approximation, we get

$$10^{78}!\approx\sqrt{2\pi} 10^{39}\left(\frac{10^{78}}{e} \right)^{10^{78}}$$
which is still *way* too big to even begin to fathom, but you probably won't get much closer to understanding this number. The real monster of this expression is $\left(10^{78}\right)^{10^{78}}$; it is approximately a $1$ followed by $10^{80}$ zeros.

[Here](https://np.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/3uzp2b/why_do_we_use_factorial_to_get_possible/cxj8b5y?context=1) is an entertaining post from Reddit trying to handle "just" $52!$, but it should put $10^{78}!$ a *bit* into perspective.

Comment: Thank you, I will read the Reddit post.

Answer (score 3):

1.It is not combination , it is permutation, no atom can be repeated.

2.Number of permutation of $10^{78}$ is not $10^{78}!$ , lookup https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

3.combination of $10^{78}$ is not $10^{78}!$, lookup https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: What do you mean by 2? Are you talking about the number of distinguishable permutations? The number of permutations of $n$ distinc objects is $n!$

Comment: @ovi, n distinct object taken n at a time, what about taken n-1, n-2,...,1 at a time?